# How to check multiple values in variable against multiple values in hash table or pscustomobject?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I would like to know how I can check multiple values against multiple values contained in a hash table or pscustomobject?

Just for context, the cmdlets used are for SharePoint.

Here`s my code so far:

```
$usersSearched = [pscustomobject]@{
DisplayName = (@("Administrator";"Service Administrator";"Company 
Administrator"))
LoginName = (@("s-1-5-21-2098222698-275879357-2441446288-39577944";"s-1-5-
21-2098222698-275179357-2441446288-39696162";"s-1-5-21-2098262698-275879357-
2441446288-14998143"))
}

#Returns object with one or more values and has a .LoginName property
$result = Get-SPOUser -Site $site | Where-Object {$_.IsSiteAdmin -eq $True}

If ($usersSearched.LoginName -in $result.LoginName)
    #Whatever
{
```

My propblem is that I am unable to get the condition to return true.
If there`re easier ways to execute this seemingly simple task, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First, have to separate entries within an array using a **comma**, *not* a semicolon:

```
$usersSearched = [PsCustomObject]@{
    DisplayName = @("Administrator","Service Administrator","Company Administrator")
    LoginName = @("s-1-5-21-2098222698-275879357-2441446288-39577944",
        "s-1-5-21-2098222698-275179357-2441446288-39696162",
        "s-1-5-21-2098262698-275879357-2441446288-14998143")
}
```

Second, you have to use `-contains` instead of `-in` (or you swap the values):

```
If ($usersSearched.LoginName -contains $result.LoginName)
```